# Best option to expose the data from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerbi

I'm looking for a way to expose data to external consumption , such as Excel or Power Bi, from SQL Server database without grant direct access to the database.
Data is stored in 1 big table, 7 milllion rows and 30 columns.

What is a recommended solution for such export?

Thanks

Comment: Well you could use the database directly in PowerBI, shape the data / query and not share the credentials (clear permissions of the data source to be sure) - the .pbix will retain the imported data but but the credentials then, when uploaded to app.powerbi.com the credentials would need to be added again to do any refresh as well

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that has a private method to create a connection to the database, and a public method GetData that accepts a sql string and returns a recordset using that private connection.

```
Private conn as ado.connection
Private sub OpenConn() 
   'code to set conn
    if not conn.state = adostateopen then
         conn.connectionstring = "put your string here" 
         conn.open
    end if
end sub

Public function GetData(s as string) as recordset
openconn
dim rs as recordset
set rs = conn.execute s
end function
```

(cue posters complaining about not sanitising inputs and executing against database etc,etc)